# How to remove this plugin error message Plugin "SVG2VectorDrawable" is incompatible

Tags: android-studio, plugins

After updating AndroidStudio to 4.1, gradle plugin to 4.1.0 and Gradle to 6.5 there is this error message at each launch of AndroidStudio

> Plugin Error: Plugin "SVG2VectorDrawable" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).

This plugin is not even installed, it is just listed in the marketplace.

Apart from this red and bold error message, no other effect is visible.
How strange isn'it ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For Windows Users:**
Open Android studio configuration directory,such as "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins"

**For Mac Users:**
Mac OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins

**Delete the plugin file or directory.**

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing! You answer just saved me 10sec per day closing the Plugin Error PopUp. Cheers!

Comment: Mac OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins

Comment: I also encountered the same error message, "SVG2VectorDrawable" is svg2android in the plugin directory. Just delete Mac OS X:~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/svg2android.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 Path is

C:\Users[your user]\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Do not forget to "show Hidden Item".